# How to write following equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to  write the following equation for my paper. I am familiar with using big braces, but I am not sure how to write multiple lines within the braces as in the image attached. 
The following gives me the left side and the huge braces:

> `$t\rightarrow_{A}t' \iff \Bigg\{ \exists C$`
>   [image]

Comment: You can insert `array` after the brace. Or `aligned` if you want to align something.

Comment: As an alternative, `cases` is also ok (although it is not really for this purpose).

Comment: with help of mathtool: `\[t \xrightarrow{\mathcal{A}} t' \Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l} xxx\\ yyy'\\ ...\end{array}\right. \]`. i can provide an answer if you will extend provide a mwe with your equation.

Comment: @JouleV Please provide a complete answer, I do not get you

Comment: @Zarko I have provided a MWE in my question

Comment: to late, not needed anymore. meanwhile others already do your job

Comment: @GermanShepherd That is Denis' answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Whoever down voted this question, I would really like to know why, it is not useful to downvote and not provide a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarising everything (had some free-time) `;-)`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$   t\xrightarrow[\mathcal{A}]{} t'\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
\exists C\in\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{F}\cup Q),\exists u_1,\ldots,u_n\in T(\mathcal{F}),\\
\exists f(q_1(x_1),\ldots,q_n(x_n))\rightarrow q(f(x_1,\ldots,x_n))\in\Delta,\\
t=C[f(q_1(u_1),\ldots,q_n(u_n))],\\
t'=C[q(f(u_1,\ldots,u_n))].
\end{cases}$        
\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

Comment: should stick that in display math

Comment: @JPi I decided to let the OP do that ;)

Comment: @Raaja This works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Summarizing the above comments, you can try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
a \iff b \iff
\begin{cases}
c = d\\
e = f
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]